# For every value in vector: extract value from an appropriate row in a dataframe

Tags: r

I think the best way to explain my question is by an example:

```
we have a vector:
vector1 (1,2,3,3,5,6,3,7,7)
and a dataframe:
ID  VAL
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h

I want to create a vector that will look like this:
vector2 (a,b,c,c,e,f,c,g,g)
```

Sounds very simple and probably is very simple with some trick that I don't know about.
I tried with "%in%" but it produced a vector of values from rows(of the dataframe) present in the vector as opposed to my goal which is a vector of values from the dataframe corresponding to the values in the vector.

Thank you.

Comment: Simply `df[vec, "VAL"]` (if `df` is your dataframe and `vec` is your vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you David, following your suggestion I was able solve my problem.
Though I needed to make some preparation (it was because I oversimplified the example)
Actually, (if we will continue with the naming convention from my example) The "ID" column had some strings so the dataframe looked like so:

```
ID      VAL
one     a
two     b
three   c
four    d
five    e
six     f
seven   g
eight   h
```

And vector1 looked like this: (one,two,three,three,five,six,three,seven,seven)
Then, I figured I should rename the rownames of the dataframe to the names in "ID" and then perform the command you have suggested.
My preparation looked like this:

```
rownames(dataframe) <- dataframe$ID
vector2 <- dataframe[vector1, "VAL"]
```

Comment: Or just use `match` as in `dataframe[match(vector1, dataframe$ID), "VAL"]`

Comment: Thank you David, You could write it all as an answer and I'll mark it as the official answer.

Comment: You can add all the info to your answer, I don't mind.